# PlatformIO ESP-IDF compiles everything to pioenvs - VSCode and Win10

Tags: visual-studio-code, esp32, platformio

I'm trying to get used to the toolchain for PlatformIO on Windows 10 over VSCode, compiling a simple project for the ESP32 (doit-devkit-v1). I have noticed two things:

When building an "Arduino" sketch, it puts very little in the .pioenvs folder in my project, and the compilation seems to take an appropriate amount of time.

When building an "ESP-IDF" project, it compiles a whole bunch of object files into that .pioenvs folder, and the compilation is a few minutes long.

I wonder if I have a problem with my setup, and I'd appreciate some advice. Like, do I have an include path set wrong, or need to add something in my platformio.ini file?

Ex:

```
Compiling .pioenvs\esp32doit-devkit-v1\bt\bluedroid\bta\dm\bta_dm_ci.o
Compiling .pioenvs\esp32doit-devkit-v1\bt\bluedroid\bta\dm\bta_dm_main.o
Compiling .pioenvs\esp32doit-devkit-v1\bt\bluedroid\bta\dm\bta_dm_pm.o
Compiling .pioenvs\esp32doit-devkit-v1\bt\bluedroid\bta\dm\bta_dm_sco.o
Compiling .pioenvs\esp32doit-devkit-v1\bt\bluedroid\bta\gatt\bta_gatt_common.o
Compiling .pioenvs\esp32doit-devkit-v1\bt\bluedroid\bta\gatt\bta_gattc_act.o
Compiling .pioenvs\esp32doit-devkit-v1\bt\bluedroid\bta\gatt\bta_gattc_api.o
Compiling .pioenvs\esp32doit-devkit-v1\bt\bluedroid\bta\gatt\bta_gattc_cache.o
Compiling .pioenvs\esp32doit-devkit-v1\bt\bluedroid\bta\gatt\bta_gattc_ci.o
Compiling .pioenvs\esp32doit-devkit-v1\bt\bluedroid\bta\gatt\bta_gattc_main.o
Compiling .pioenvs\esp32doit-devkit-v1\bt\bluedroid\bta\gatt\bta_gattc_utils.o
Compiling .pioenvs\esp32doit-devkit-v1\bt\bluedroid\bta\gatt\bta_gatts_act.o
Compiling .pioenvs\esp32doit-devkit-v1\bt\bluedroid\bta\gatt\bta_gatts_api.o
Compiling .pioenvs\esp32doit-devkit-v1\bt\bluedroid\bta\gatt\bta_gatts_main.o
Compiling .pioenvs\esp32doit-devkit-v1\bt\bluedroid\bta\gatt\bta_gatts_utils.o
Compiling .pioenvs\esp32doit-devkit-v1\bt\bluedroid\bta\hh\bta_hh_act.o
Compiling .pioenvs\esp32doit-devkit-v1\bt\bluedroid\bta\hh\bta_hh_api.o
Compiling .pioenvs\esp32doit-devkit-v1\bt\bluedroid\bta\hh\bta_hh_cfg.o
Compiling .pioenvs\esp32doit-devkit-v1\bt\bluedroid\bta\hh\bta_hh_le.o
Compiling .pioenvs\esp32doit-devkit-v1\bt\bluedroid\bta\hh\bta_hh_main.o
```

...etc.